# Combining Class and Nth-Child in Perl TreeBuilder and XPath

Tags: perl, xpath, html-treebuilder

I am trying to get the sum of a column in an html table.  The first row of this table is all titles.  Every cell of every row past the first has the class "right", so I was going to use that class as a selector to ignore the unnecessary titles.  However, I only need the second cell of each row.  How do I combine these two selectors?  Is this right?

```
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath->new_from_file($fileName);
foreach $value ($tree->findnodes('//table/tr/td[@class="right"[position()=2]')){
    stuff;
}
```

Comment: There are two left square brackets, but only one right square bracket. It is probably not right.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine the predicates by just putting one after another:

```
//table/tr/td[@class="right"][2]
```

or, you can use the logical `and`

```
//table/tr/td[@class="right" and position()=2]
```

Comment: So this would be correct for adding the value of each of these cells?

    foreach $val ($tree->findnodes('//table/tr/td[@class="right"][2])){
      $sum += $val->findvalue();
     }

Comment: If you just want to sum, you can use XPath function sum(): `sum(//table/tr/td[@class="right"][2])`

Comment: Hold on--would using this notation give me all <td> cells that are second children, or would it give me the second children of <td> cells?

Comment: @user2933738: `[position()=2]` and `[2]` mean the same in XPath. `parent/element[2]` returns the second `element` child of `parent`. To get the second child of `element`, you would need `parent/element/*[2]`.

Comment: Okay.  So, in order to get the "right" class, second child of <tr>, I would say this?

findnodes('//table/tr[2][@class="right"]')

Or would that get me the second child of of "right" class tr objects?

Comment: @user2933738: No, check the documentation and my answer.